# MTurk Submission Issue: Target origin does not match recipient window's origin

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services

I am working on releasing HITs to MTurk. I have been doing this for years now without changing the core files. Recently, I encountered an error that does not allow the Turkers to submit their HITs:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided
('https://worker.mturk.com') does not match the recipient window's origin 
('https://www.mturk.com').
```

We use ExternalQuestions, but we post to `https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit?`, followed by the assignment ID. All of which seems to be accurate according to [MTurk Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html).

Our I-frame url points to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/` followed by the parameters specific to the HIT type.

This is a new issue that we have encountered. We have not changed any of our code, and it was working perfectly fine ~ a month ago. I know there were some changes to the worker's site, but I can't see how it would be affecting us. I have been attempting to solve this problem, but am still at a loss. Any help is appreciated.